# SQL query aggregate multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is like so:

```
SELECT A.director, COUNT(*) as NumActors
FROM CanWorkWith A
GROUP BY A.director
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

The CanWorkWith Table:

```
CanWorkWith(actor, director)
```

This query will return only the directors that have ATLEAST 5 actors that they can work with.

So, now I want to take the result of this query, and search another table to count the number of movies said director(s) have.

So, if the director has 5 actors, then I want to search for that director in a table called:

```
Movies (title, year, director, budget, earnings)
```

And then finally, return the director, and the TOTAL count of Titles that director has, doing this for all the directors with more than 5 actors.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a JOIN between this result and the query that returns the number of movies per director.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    M.director, 
    COUNT(M.title) as 'Number of movies',
    D.NumActors
FROM Movies M
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT A.director, COUNT(*) as NumActors
        FROM CanWorkWith A
        GROUP BY A.director
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
   ) D ON M.director = D.director
GROUP BY M.director, 
         D.NumActors
```

Comment: @user3015190 Don't forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct if it has worked for you.